# How to wait until method from another class in asynctask finishes in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am newbie in AsyncTask, and I got problem.
I have AsyncTask, which saves info in DB by calling function from another class. The problem is that onPostExecute method is calling before my function finishes; Here is my code:

```
class checkNewReviews2 extends AsyncTask<List<ReviewList.ReviewItem>, Void, Void>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<ReviewList.ReviewItem>... reviewList) {

        int size = reviewList[0].size();
        if(size>0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                ReviewList.ReviewItem r = reviewList[0].get(i);
                ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.FILM_ID, r.getFilm_id());
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.USER_ID, r.getUser_id());
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.REVIEW_TEXT, r.getReview_text());
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.CREATED_AT, r.getCreated_at());
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.REVIEW_TYPE, r.getReview_type());
                c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.VIEWS, r.getViews());
                sqLiteDatabase.insert(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, c);

                c.clear();
            }
            FilmHandler filmHandler = new FilmHandler(getContext());
            filmHandler.HandleFilms(reviewList[0]);
            UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler(getContext());
            userHandler.HandleUsers(reviewList[0]);


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        initiateRecyclerView();
    }
}
```

I already tried to put all calls into onPreExecute, but the result is still the same. Also as a notice, the first block of sql code (cycle) is succesfully handled, not as Film and User handlers. How should I call initiateRecyclerView after AsyncTask completely executed?

Comment: `The problem is that onPostExecute method is calling before my function finishes` Probably you are using other  Thread's  from `doInBackground` workThread

Comment: onPostExecute will execute only after completion of doInBackground. If the FilmHandler and Userhandler are implemented on separate thread , it can cause the issue.So to avoid this,do not use another thread to save data in DB instead complete the entire saving data in the doInBackground itself.

Comment: So how could I run FilmHandler and UserHandler int the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your `doInBackgound()` method needs to "wait" for your `FilmHandler`, `UserHandler` classes to finish.

My guess is that your classes are working on a background thread so when you use them your code immediately continues to the `return null` statement - and finishing the background work, causing `onPostExecute()` to be called.

Change your classes implementation to work on the calling thread and not create their own.

Comment: Is there any example on how to implement the use of calling thread?

Comment: That would be very specific and way beyond what I could exsplain in stackOverFlow. I suggest you'll start by reading the source code of the classes and see what async techniques theyre using (Thread,  AsyncTask etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add context to doinbackground parameter as well.Might be getcontext returning null/Application Context

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute will execute only after completion of doInBackground. If the FilmHandler and Userhandler are implemented on separate thread , it can cause the issue. So to avoid this,do not use another thread to save data in DB (or) Performing some other sort of operatio instead complete the entire saving data in the doInBackground itself.

Else there is an another way which also you can archive the functionality. You need to add a call back for the filmHandler or userHandler functions and check for the update in doinBackground and based on it you can pass the result to PostExcecute()

```
class checkNewReviews2 extends AsyncTask<List<ReviewList.ReviewItem>, Void, Boolean>{


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(List<ReviewList.ReviewItem>... reviewList) {

    int size = reviewList[0].size();
    if(size>0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ReviewList.ReviewItem r = reviewList[0].get(i);
            ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.FILM_ID, r.getFilm_id());
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.USER_ID, r.getUser_id());
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.REVIEW_TEXT, r.getReview_text());
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.CREATED_AT, r.getCreated_at());
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.REVIEW_TYPE, r.getReview_type());
            c.put(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.VIEWS, r.getViews());
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(LentaClass.LentaListEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, c);

            c.clear();
        }


        FilmHandler filmHandler = new FilmHandler(YourActivity.this);
       boolean filmHandlerState =   filmHandler.HandleFilms(reviewList[0]);
        UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler(YourActivity.this);
      boolean userHandlerState =   userHandler.HandleUsers(reviewList[0]);



        if(filmHandlerState && userHandlerState )
        {
        return true;
        } 
       else
       {
       return false;
       }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

      if(result)
     {
       initiateRecyclerView();
     }
     else
     {
      // any one of the filmHandler or userHandler function has failed. so do your handling here 

}
```

}

In another point as stated by @user3413619 might be getContext() is returning null so, try to make it YourActivity.this

Comment: I forgot to add, that this code is in Fragment, so I cant use Activity.this

Comment: Then you have to add getActivity() instead of getContext(). try this with your old codes

Comment: I changed as you said but the problem still remains

Comment: I tried, but its failed because my Handlers dont return any value, so I tried to create new AsyncTask in Handlers to obtain any result and return back to Fragment, but this new AsyncTask failed T_T.

Answer (score 0):

make doInBackground method return type boolean and pass result to postExecute boolean then check if result true do what method you want to call.

Thanks